# how can i convert decoded transaction input value

Tags: web3js

sorry for my broken english.
i can decode transaction input hash with web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters.
but i can convert _value data human readable. i try hex, bignumber but i failed.
how can i convert value data attached pic.

[image]

how can i convert 600000000 to 600.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion is a simple division by the number of decimals for each token.
for USDT, the decimals are equal to 6 so all values processed by the contract have 6 decimals which means that 600000000 = 600 USDT tokens.

The decimals are the definition of how much can a token be fractured, in this case it's only to a 10e-6 value.

the decimals are also avaialble from the main token contract, you can find it in the [Read Contract section](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#readContract) of the token on etherscan